# Duplicated Data in Traces after Plot Update

Tags: javascript, plot, plotly

This problem seems to be intermittent. I have to refresh the browser several times for it to show up.

As seen on the image, after `setup()` and at the beginning of `loop`, the traces get duplicated in the `plot.data` object, resulting in a overlapping line.

This somehow is related to the data instances keeping a copy at `x0` and so in the `plot.data` object, then resulting duplicated.

The code is below.

Hope somebody can give me a guideline on how to override this bug ([ref.](https://community.plotly.com/t/extend-traces-connecting-back-to-beginning/9941/))

JS

```
// VARS
var layout,config;
var T=30,Ti=3,dt=1.0/10;
var lx=Math.ceil(T/dt),lxi=Math.ceil(Ti/dt);
var dte=Ti;
var oint;
var t0i=[],x0i=[],i0i=[],l0i=0;
// PLOT SETUP
function setup(){
    // DATE
    t0=new Date();
    t0.setTime(Math.round(t0.getTime()/1000.0)*1000.0);
    tk=t0;
    var tkn=new Date(),tkm=new Date();
    // DATA
    var lx0=lx;
    var i=0
        t0i[i]=[];
        x0i[i]=[];
        i0i[i]=i;
        for(var j=0;j<lx0;j++){
            t0i[i][j]=new Date();
            t0i[i][j].setTime(tk.getTime()-T*1000*(lx0-j-1)/lx);
            x0i[i][j]=Math.round(t0i[0][j].getTime()/1000)%5;
        }
    // NEXT INDEX
    l0i=l0i+lx0;        
    tk.setTime(t0i[0][l0i-1].getTime()+Ti*1000.0/lxi);
    // TRACES
    var data=[],trace=[];
    var i=0
        trace[i] = {
            x: t0i[i],
            y: x0i[i],
            mode: 'lines'
        };
    // LAYOUT
    layout = {
        xaxis: {
            type:'date'
        }
    };
    // CONFIG
    var config={
        displayModeBar: false
    };
    Plotly.newPlot('plot',trace,layout,config);
}
// PLOT LOOP
function loop(){
    // DATA0
    var t0k=new Date();
    var t01i=[],x01i=[];
    var i=0;
        t01i[i]=[];
        x01i[i]=[];
        for (var j=0;j<lxi;j++){
            // READ NEW DATA
            t0i[i][j+l0i]=new Date();
            t0i[i][j+l0i].setTime(t0i[0][j+l0i-1].getTime()+Ti*1000.0/lxi);
            x0i[i][j+l0i]=Math.round(t0i[0][j+l0i].getTime()/1000)%5;
            t01i[i][j]=t0i[i][j+l0i];
            x01i[i][j]=x0i[i][j+l0i];
        }       
    l0i=l0i+lxi;
    tk.setTime(t0i[0][l0i-1].getTime()+Ti*1000.0/lxi);  
    var trace1 = {
        x:t01i,
        y:x01i
    };
    // PLOT
    var tn=new Date(),tm=new Date();
    tn.setTime(tk.getTime()-T*1000);
    tm.setTime(tk.getTime());
    var layout={
        'xaxis.range' : [tn,tm],
        'yaxis.range' : 0.5*[-1,1],
        'title.font.size': 12
      };
    Plotly.extendTraces('plot',trace1,i0i);
    Plotly.relayout('plot',layout);
}
// MAIN
function main(){
    setup();
    oint=setInterval(loop,dte*1000);
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head><script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
     <script src="chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="main();"><div id="plot"></div></body>
</html>
```

[image]